# Colisiones en canvas html5 juego

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Espero que esten teniendo un buen dia. Vengo para aca porque tengo un problema de colisiones en canvas... Estoy creando o intentando crear mi primer jjuego con canvas y javascript. Estoy por la parte de colisiones, la cual no me funciona, no entiendo por que. Ya he intentado arios algoritmos, he intentado uno basico hecho por mi y nada. No veo donde esta el problea espero me pueda ayudar. Mucas gracias

Aqui dejo el full code: https://codepen.io/telpro/pen/POKQYr

y aqui dejo las partes especifias:

```
function creandoEnemigos(numeroEnemigos){  //CREATING ENEMIES
        for(var i=0;i<numeroEnemigos;i++){
            ctx.fillStyle='yellow';
            ctx.fillRect(enemigos[i].posX,enemigos[i].posY,enemigos[i].width,enemigos[i].height);
            //ctx.drawImage(enemy,enemigos[i].posX,enemigos[i].posY);   
        }   
    }

    function moviendoEnemigos(){   //moving enemies
        for(var i=0;i<numeroEnemigos;i++){
            //ctx.clearRect(enemigos[i].posX,enemigos[i].posY,enemigos[i].width,enemigos[i].height);
            enemigos[i].posX+=enemigos[i].velocidad; //va a moverse con la operacion: + n veces sea declarada la variable velocidad
        }
        for(var j=0;j<numeroEnemigos;j++){
            if(enemigos[j].posX>canvas.width){
                timerEnemy++;
                enemigos[j].posX=0;
                enemigos[j].posY+=2;
            }
            if(enemigos[j].posY==canvas.height/2){
                enemigos[j].posX=0;
                enemigos[j].posY-=200;
            }
        }
    }

    function creandoDisparos(){ //CREATING BULLETS
        //se crea instancia del objecto disparosJson
        var disp = new disparosJson(canonJson.posX+5, disparosJsonStartValues.posY+30, disparosJsonStartValues.width, disparosJsonStartValues.height)
        //agregamos al arreglo el nuevo disparo
        arrayDisparos[arrayDisparos.length] = disp;
        if(arrayDisparos.length>20){
           /*intervaloBalas=window.setInterval(function(){
                alert("Balas agotadas, espera 5 segundos...");
            },2000); */
        }
    }

    function moviendoDisparos(){ //MOVING BULLETS
        ctx.fillStyle='white';
        for(var i=0;i<arrayDisparos.length;i++){
            let disp = arrayDisparos[i];
            //clear space of bullet
            ctx.clearRect(disp.posX1,disp.posY,disp.width,disp.height);
            disp.posY-=2.2;
            //draw space of bullet
            ctx.fillRect(disp.posX1,disp.posY,disp.width,disp.height);  
        }
    }

    function disparar(){
        creandoDisparos(); 
    }

    function colisionObjetos(){ //FUNCTION COLLISION

        var colision= false;
        if (arrayDisparos.posX < enemigos.posX + enemigos.width  && arrayDisparos.posX + arrayDisparos.width  > enemigos.posX &&
        arrayDisparos.posY < enemigos.posY + enemigos.height && arrayDisparos.posY + arrayDisparos.height > enemigos.posY){
            colision=true;
        }
            if(colision){
                alert("coli detected");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tus variables son arrays, entonces tienes que accederlas con notacion [].

```
enemigos[i].posX
```

en vez de

```
enemigos.posX
```